# How to get only parent products of a particular manufacturer using Product collection Model

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to get only parent product of a particular manufacurer using product collection Model. I tried below code-

```
$brand_id=23;  // a manufacturer option value
$manufacturerId = $brand_id;
$attributeCode = 'manufacturer';
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

below is the screenshot showing what I am trying to do-
   [image]

in above image I am getting all parent + child products. I only want to get parent products.
I have used tried [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17157/how-to-get-only-child-categories-of-a-product-magento-1-8-1) but no luck, can anyone guide me how can I do that.

Comment: have you created product name attribute? What is relation between product name attribute and brand?

Comment: How you define a product is parent products.Actually this not default magento feature So i have asking

Answer (score 1):

**Change your product collection something like this and try**

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $manufacturerId)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

$_productCollection->joinTable('catalog/product_relation', 'child_id=entity_id', array(
            'parent_id' => 'parent_id'
        ), null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array(
                'attribute' => 'parent_id',
                'null' => null
            )
        ));
```